# How to release a golang package with binary file？

Tags: go

```bash
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── binaries
│   ├── init.go
│   ├── linux
│   │   └── adb
│   ├── mac
│   │   └── adb
│   └── win
│       ├── AdbWinApi.dll
│       ├── AdbWinUsbApi.dll
│       └── adb.exe
├── client.go
├── device.go
├── examples
│   └── base.go
├── go.mod
├── proto.go
└── test
    ├── adb_test.go
    └── pack_test.go

6 directories, 15 files
```

This is my project, I released a version,  and I use `go get xxxxx`, what I get this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWiB8.png)

the `linx` `win` `mac` dir is gone, what should I do to keep those file and keep them can execute?

this is repo URL https://github.com/xmsociety/adbutils

Comment: You could just use `git clone`.

Comment: `go get` will only ever download the source files. It is for pulling dependencies. A package cannot depend on anything outside the source, because it won't be there after it's compiled. If you want other files, you'll have to check out the git repo instead of using `go get`.

Answer (score 0):

what you looking for is

```
   go install github.com/****/*****
```

it will create a binary file on GOPATH/bin/
after then you can use execute from terminal
if the system can't find binary put exports in your .bashrc

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```